# In TFS, find all child Tasks where Iteration field doesn't match parent

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I would like to create a TFS work item query that will return all items where the parent item *Iteration* field does not match the child's *Iteration* field.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to configure in the UI. You can do this in PowerShell by calling the API and iterating through the work items.